# How to transfer file from local disk to Cloudera Virtual Machine? (I've looked through SO and found nothing)

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

This is pretty trivial, so trivial that I haven't been able to find anything on here.

So, my task is quite simple. Take a simple .txt file and transfer it onto an hdfs directory in cloudera.

I've tried this:

[image]

but no luck. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to post an image to demonstrate a command-line effort? Do you not know how to copy/paste from a terminal window?

Comment: Since my terminal is in the VM, I can't copy it and paste it here. This was the quickest way to relay that information.

Comment: From the question, it is not clear that whether you want to copy `from host machine to VM` or `VM to HDFS` or `host machine to VM to HDFS`.

Comment: if I got your question right, [you should try this](https://www.howtogeek.com/187703/how-to-access-folders-on-your-host-machine-from-an-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have already copied files to VM and you are logged into VM (linux), the command you should be using is:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <local-linux-path> <hdfs-path>
```

If you don't have your home directory created on HDFS, then create it first using:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/madhav/
```

The path you are giving in the command you have shown looks wrong to me. It should look something like:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/madhav/file.txt /user/madhav/
```

Then you can check your file on hdfs with:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/madhav/
```